# What is better to use Class of Def in views

Tags: python, django, function, class, view

I have a question that bothers me.

What is better to use in django views? Classes or defs? And if both, so when using it? When to deviate from a given method.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if the view can be explained by simply specifying or overriding a small amount of methods, use the class-based view that matches the best, if the view does something that is not very standard, use a function-based view.

Comment: See for example this diagram: https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-class-based-views-vs-function-based-view-e74b47b2e41b

Answer (score 0):

for readability flow of your app task use function base view